Boundedness of the Laplacian Eigenfunctions
I have a doubt regarding the Laplacian eigenfunctions $\left\{\phi_n\right\}_{n=1}^\infty$ with Dirichlet boundary conditions. I know that the functions form an orthonormal basis in $L^2$ and an orthogonal basis in $H^1_0$ (equipped with the inner product $(u, v)_{H^1_0} = (\nabla u, \nabla v)_{L^2})$.
Does the eigenfunctions form an orthonormal basis also in $H_0^1$?
If not, is there a constant such that $\|\phi_n\|_{H^1_0} \le C$ for all $n$?

Hint: $H_0^1\to L^2$ is a compact embedding.

No. Denote the eigenvalues by $\lambda_n$, so that $- \Delta \phi_n = \lambda_n \phi_n$. Testing this with $\phi_n$ itself shows
$$
\|\nabla \phi_n \|_{L^2}^2 = \lambda_n \|\phi_n\|_{L^2}^2 = \lambda_n,
$$
which is unbounded as $n\to\infty$.
